how to kill the process that always restart in macOS
when I using this command to check which process using the port in macOS:
lsof -i:9099

show info like this:
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  166u  IPv4 0x313b3790f32e9601      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55209 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  167u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2cd2c21      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55675 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  168u  IPv4 0x313b3790f31d13a1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54050 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  169u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2d0a111      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55441 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  170u  IPv4 0x313b3790f3238af1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55676 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  171u  IPv4 0x313b3790f33113a1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55677 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  172u  IPv4 0x313b3790f32bd601      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54288 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  173u  IPv4 0x313b3790f3dbac21      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54289 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  174u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2bdf4d1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55828 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  176u  IPv4 0x313b3790f3384891      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55871 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  182u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2d134d1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54051 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  189u  IPv4 0x313b3790f4dc93a1      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54291 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  210u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2cf8891      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54995 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  217u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2cf1601      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:54997 (CLOSED)
ProxyPin  14893 xiaoqiangjiang  230u  IPv4 0x313b3790f2c85601      0t0  TCP localhost:9099->localhost:55002 (CLOSED)

then using this command to terminal the process:
kill -9 14893

but the proces still exists, just changed to another process id. why did this happen? the proxyPin was an http(s) proxy tool from here: https://github.com/wanghongenpin/proxypin. how to kill the process which using port 9099?

You are killing that process. Your problem is identifying what launch daemon or other process restarts it, no? Your title and fix are not going to help as you’re focused on the symptom and not the cause. Is there an uninstalled for proxy pin or a manual?
